# Link error with `boost::log2_mt` only on Ubuntu 32/64bits

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, boost, linker

I have a huge project in which i use boost. boost come with my source tree in a specific folder where are header and lib for gcc 32 bits and 64bits in separate sub folder.

on Centos : `Linux .... SMP Tue Jun 12 09:58:12 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
No problem every link fine.

But the same source tree on Ubuntu: `Linux ... 3.2.0-48-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 19:43:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` fails dure to a linker error.

```
libtest.so: undefined reference to `boost::log2_mt_posix::aux::sem_based_event::~sem_based_event()'
libtest.so: undefined reference to `boost::log2_mt_posix::aux::sem_based_event::sem_based_event()'
libtest.so: undefined reference to `boost::log2_mt_posix::aux::sem_based_event::set_signalled()'
libtest.so: undefined reference to `boost::log2_mt_posix::aux::sem_based_event::wait()'
```

below is the whole linker command line... Any help would be welcome !

```
/usr/bin/ccache  g++      -m32 -lrt -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/build/lin32_release -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/boost/Lin32 -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/ace/Lin32 -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/SafeNetRMS/Lin32 -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/OpenSSL/bin/out32StaticMTReleaseLinux -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/TinyXML/Lin32/ReleaseStaticMT -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/zlib/Lin32 -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/Curl/Lin32 -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/microhttpd/Lin32 -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/Intel/Linux32 -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/IPP/Lin32 -L/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Source/../Libs/xerces/lin32 CMakeFiles/Frameworktst.dir/Framework/FrameworkTst/FrameworkTimerTst.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Frameworktst.dir/Framework/FrameworkTst/FrameworkTst.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Frameworktst.dir/Framework/FrameworkTst/WriterTst.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Frameworktst.dir/Framework/FrameworkTst/FrameworkLogTst.cpp.o  -o Frameworktst  libFramework.so libVersionInfoLib.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_system-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_signals-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log_setup-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread -ldl -lrt libTestMediaPlugin.so libFramework.so libVersionInfoLib.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_system-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_signals-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log_setup-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread -ldl -lrt libTestAlgorithmPlugin.so libFramework.so libVersionInfoLib.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_system-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_signals-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log_setup-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread -ldl -lrt libTestChannel.so libFramework.so libVersionInfoLib.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_system-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_signals-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log_setup-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread -ldl -lrt libYaffut.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_system-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_signals-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log_setup-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread libWMCommon.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_system-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_signals-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log_setup-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_thread-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_system-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_signals-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log_setup-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -lpthread /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_system-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_date_time-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_signals-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log-gcc41-mt-1_49.a /home/abuisson/dev/fwk/Libs/boost/Lin32/libboost_log_setup-gcc41-mt-1_49.a -ldl -lrt -Wl,-rpath,/home/abuisson/dev/fwk/build/lin32_release
libFramework.so: undefined reference to `boost::log2_mt_posix::aux::sem_based_event::~sem_based_event()'
libFramework.so: undefined reference to `boost::log2_mt_posix::aux::sem_based_event::sem_based_event()'
libFramework.so: undefined reference to `boost::log2_mt_posix::aux::sem_based_event::set_signalled()'
libFramework.so: undefined reference to `boost::log2_mt_posix::aux::sem_based_event::wait()'
```

Comment: did you follow [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation/config.html)?

Comment: @TemplateRex, In fact not as I use a packaged version, and I use exactly the same .a and .hpp files on Centos and Ubuntu. The thing I don't understand is how can I meet a link error on only 1 platform ? if something is missing I should have the same error on both !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also had the same issue and found that the symbol "sem_based_event" indeed does not exist in the library. Then the question is why, the header of this class "sem_based_event" is being included.

The issue is caused because we try to use boost library built with gcc 4.1 on a platform with gcc 4.4 or greater.

the class sem_based_event is enabled/included based on a flag "__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_4" which was introduced in gcc 4.3. So, when we build the boost library with version 4.1, this class is not included/enabled. However, this flag is for both definition as well as the declaration of the class "sem_based_event". On Platform with gcc 4.1 (CentOs5.7), the declaration is also disabled and we donot see any linker errors. However, on platforms with gcc 4.4 or greater (e.g. Ubuntu 10.10), the declaration of the class "sem_based_event" will be enabled during compilation and if we still try to link it against boost log library built with 4.1, it will not be able to find the symbol and thus cause the above mentioned error.

How to Fix it:

Use the correct compiled version of boost library i.e. compile the boost library with the same gcc version with which you are going to use it.